# Get email address for receiver from node field

Tags: 7, rules, entities

I have site where is +300 different workshop nodes (one conent type). All workshops should have contact form in node page.

Is it possible with Entityform pull email from node field to form receiver email? So that I dont have to manually make +300 contact forms with right receiver email addresses?

Entityform uses Rules to send email. So what I did:

I cloned Email Entityform Submitter and added Node variable to it.
Then added Condition: Content is type of Workshop. And edited Send mail with Variable to set data-selector to node:field-email.

But when submitting form I'm getting this error:

> RulesEvaluationException: Argument node is missing. in RulesPlugin->setUpState() (line 652 of /public_html/sites/all/modules/rules/includes/rules.core.inc).

Any ideas how to make this work?

Comment: did u use entity reference module to embed entity forms  into nodes?

Comment: I'm using views to show entityform in node. I should somehow use entity reference module to embed forms into nodes?

Comment: Now changed it to embed to node with Entity reference field, but still getting same error.

Comment: can you send me screenshot of your node workshop view?